# Nonsensical windbg thread output (symbols loaded correctly)

Tags: java, c++, debugging, windbg

I have a project that uses Java to do GUI and C++ to do computations, connected via JNI. I have a deadlock in the app that manifests itself after 3+ hours. I thought I would debug using WinDBG. So I attached the app as a debuggee, loaded the correct symbols and started viewing call stacks. The problem is, the call stacks I am getting seem to not correspond to what the app is doing.

For example, I have about 10 worker threads, all opened by

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, &(work), this, 0, NULL);
```

but the windbg shows only one such thread. I also have at least two dozens threads whose identical call stacks look like this:

```
wow64cpu!CpupSyscallStub
wow64cpu!Thunk0ArgReloadState
wow64!RunCpuSimulation
wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize
ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess
ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk
```

What are those?

Then I have a thread whose stack trace consists of single function repeated all over again:

```
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
myModule!myFunc
```

The `myFunc` function is NOT recursive and does NOT start its own threads. How is it possible that the stack looks like this? Where is the rest of the stack trace?

There is no thread that would operate in javaw module (and there should be at least one - the EDT)

How can I make the debugger correctly identify threads and make it display real stack traces?

Also... is it possible to label threads in some way so that they can be identified in the debugger?

EDIT more info:
For licensing purposes I cannot use Visual Studio.
WinDBG version: 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Windows 7, 6.1 build 7601, SP1
Java 1.7.0_07

I use Eclipse CDT and for optimization I can choose only "Default", "Minimize Size" and "Maximize Speed". I use "Default". My compiling command looks like this: `cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi` When I display disassembly, it shows assembly code for functions in module, not the original source code. However, it opens source files from the source location.

Comment: The ntdll at the bottom is process creation, wow64 and wow64cpu are initialization and running of 32bit code on a 64bit processor. You can pretty much ignore all of them at the bottom. Usually you want to start looking from where your known entry point function is. Even the MSVCRT adds _crtWinMain or something like that before your real "main" or "WinMain" is called.

Comment: @NtscCobalt The problem is that I start the app as a Jar file, then loads a DLL and access that DLL by JNI. The DLL then starts its own worker threads... and even those do not have call stack that make sense.

Comment: even CreateThread adds some functions such as ntdll!RtInitiliazeExceptionChain() and then kernal32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() beyond that though you should start seeing your own functions. Are you sure you have loaded the debugging symbols for your dll (the pdb) and aren't testing an optimized dll? You should also be able to see offsets such as myModule!myFunc() + 0x15. Don't forget to that you can connect Visual Studio to existing processes. I usually only use WinDBG when I can't recreate the issue and I need to debug on a client machine.

Comment: Is your C++ module built with optimizations disabled? Please add information about the versions for everything involved (Windows, Java, WinDbg, anything else that might be relevant). Also, if you disassemble functions in WinDbg, does the code look correct?

Comment: You will have a much better debugging experience if you use the 32 bit version of Windbg.

Comment: You should use ``.effmach x86` before inspecting the thread stacks. The wow64cpu output is typical for the 64-bit native stack of a WOW64 32-bit thread.